# Hide app in django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I have [django-admin-interface](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-admin-interface) installed in my django app. I configured layout using this plugin and I would like to hide it from admin panel. My goal is to store basic settings in database. Is it possible?

I can't find any relations in my code to this plugin. There is only one place in my code (settings.py) where phrase admin_interface appears.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mainapp.apps.MainappConfig',
    'admin_interface',
    'colorfield',
    'flat_responsive',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'smart_selects',
    'activatable_model',
    'bootstrap3',
    'mainapp.apps.ConstanceConfig',
    'constance.backends.database',
    'kronos',
    'ckeditor',
    'django_admin_listfilter_dropdown',
]
```

Is is possible to hide this area in admin panel?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`unregister`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L127) in your `admin.py`.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from admin_interface.models import Theme

admin.site.unregister(Theme)
```

#### Note:

If you have multiple apps and hence multiple admin.py, then adding this snippet in anyone of them will hide the app

Comment: I get an error: django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model Theme is not registered

Comment: You should add 'django.contrib.sites' in your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Thank you - it works:) I put 'admin_interface' in front of my installed apps in settings.py and it is ok.